# how to get data from popup.js to background.js

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

By developing below code ,

**Popup.js**

```
 $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 5,
      min: 1,
      max: 15,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        var port = chrome.extension.connect({
              name: "Sample Communication"
         });
         port.postMessage(ui.value);

      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
  } );
```

**Background.js (listener)**

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
      port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
           timer=msg;
      });
 })
    $(function(){

         interval = 1000 * 60 * timer; // where X is your every X minutes
         setInterval(func1, parseInt(interval));
         setInterval(func2,300);

    });
```

**Background.js (Load Data)**

```
$.get('link', 
            function(data)
        {  
            if (data.total != 0) {

                    $.each(data.issues, function(k, v) {
                      if (!list.some(function(o) {
                          return o.key === v.key
                        }))
                        list.push({
                          "key": v.key,
                          "title": v.title,
                          "sent": false
                        });
                    }); 
                    //console.log(list);
                }
        });
```

But when I wann to test it, with dynamic value for interval, faced error which contain

> net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Can some assist me to why i get this error while I use it as a dynamic but when i use specific value as a number it is work fine.

**Update**
as i checked issue is related to default value is 0,
so the wrong thing is when i change the progress value nothing changed in my background js as I check console.log and every time i click on extension button in popup the value is default and change does not save.

Comment: If your timer variable is initially 0 or undefined, setInterval will run thousands or millions of times per second.

Comment: Its as easy as `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`.  No need for messaging or whatever the heck you're trying to do.

Comment: @wOxxOm the default is 5000

Comment: @MarcGuiselin how its work

Comment: @programmer.okz I suspect that `timer` is not set globally. Hence when you run `timer = msg;` that `timer` does not exist when you run `interval = 1000 * 60 * timer;`

Comment: @programmer.okz it is declared in global scope.

Comment: Are you aware that you can access background page from popup.js? And for the simplest actions you don't have to ajax

Comment: @Dzmtrs i used chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest the following:

```
var timer = 0;
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if(!isNaN(msg)){
      timer = parseInt(msg);
    }
  });
});
$(function(){
  var interval = 1000 * 60 * timer; // where X is your every X minutes
  setInterval(func1, interval);
  setInterval(func2, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` ([Link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage))

> Returns the JavaScript 'window' object for the background page running inside the current extension. Returns null if the extension has no background page.

So if you want to store smth in the background page or to even execute a method defined there, just use this method in your popup.js. Let's say you have a property in your background page:

```
testProp = "hi";
```

Then in popup you can either access the value or set it:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (page) {
    // Do what you want with the page
    page.testProp = "test from the popup";
});
```

You can send some data to the background page in this way and then it'll be stored there. You can invoke functions from the background page, etc.